# How to handle joins with gorp?

Tags: postgresql, go, gorp

In a hobby project of mine, I have a struct like this:

```
type Resource struct {
    Id int
    ParentIds []int
    Title string
    Contents []byte
    Resources []Resource
}
```

Each resource possibly has some sub-resources ([]Resource). I'd like to get started by using a query-to-struct mapper like [gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp), but I don't know how I can map a query like

```
SELECT r.Id, r.Title, r.Contents
FROM Resources r
LEFT OUTER JOIN Resources sub ON sub.ParentIds @> ARRAY[r.Id]::integer[]
```

Can anyone create a minimal working example or point me to a relevant documentation? Maybe gorp isn't the right tool for the job? If there is a better alternative, I'm also open to suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of a join in the gorp readme at https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp .  I don't think there is any built-in way of putting separate tables into arrays like you are doing.

Where InvoicePersonView is a struct to hold the results of the query.

```
// Run your query
query := "select i.Id InvoiceId, p.Id PersonId, i.Memo, p.FName " +
    "from invoice_test i, person_test p " +
    "where i.PersonId = p.Id"

// pass a slice to Select()
var list []InvoicePersonView
_, err := dbmap.Select(&list, query)

// this should test true
expected := InvoicePersonView{inv1.Id, p1.Id, inv1.Memo, p1.FName}
if reflect.DeepEqual(list[0], expected) {
    fmt.Println("Woot! My join worked!")
}
```